# IP special purpose address (255)

Tags: ip

So i have a one question. In example we have a C class network 192.168.0.0. My question is about special purpose address - translation address. So i have 2 options: one is `192.168.0.255` and another one is `192.168.255.255`.

Which one is correct? and why?

Comment: That depends on your network setup, on the "network mask" to be specific. A network definition without the specification of the mask is not complete. It does not make sense without form a technical point of view. So what is your network mask? For `192.168.0.0/24` the answer would be `192.168.0.255`, since `192.168.255.255` would be _outside_ the network.

Comment: mask is 255.255.255.0

Comment: That is the same as mentioned above: `192.168.0.0/24`, just another notation of "24 bits as network, remaining 8bits as host".

Comment: and if mask would be 255.255.0.0 then correct translation address would be 192.168.255.255 ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "translation address". For me in such a network the address `192.168.0.255` would be the "broadcast address" since it is used to broadcast to all hosts simultaneously.

Comment: Yea i mean the same, just didint know how to say in english, sorry ^^

Comment: OK, back to your last question: "yes"! So if your network is `192.168.0.0/16`, so `192.168.0.0` with a mask of `255.255.0.0`, then the broadcast address is `192.168.255.255`. Take a look here: http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=192.168.0.0&mask1=16&mask2=255.255.0.0